# boto3's download_file function fails on large file

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

The code (part of boto3 library)

```
download_file('BUCKET_NAME', 'OBJECT_NAME', 'FILE_NAME')
```

has been running for many years stopped working with error [Errno 95] Operation not supported when the OBJECT_NAME is larger than 8.5 MB. It still works for small files. We tried a 2.5 MB file and it worked perfectly. Is it possible to set the file size of the OBJECT_NAME?

According to pkg_resources.get_distribution("boto3").version, I am using 1.12.0.

Comment: this perhaps? add in the Config argument... https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/customizations/s3.html#boto3.s3.transfer.TransferConfig

Comment: Thank you Jonathan Leon. Tried different configurations -- same error message.

Comment: Perhaps try a different method like downlaod_file obj or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found discussions in https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2040 provided the following sample code showing how to specify larger files. Adding the Config=config worked for us.

```
GB = 1024 ** 3
config = TransferConfig(multipart_threshold=2*GB)
s3.meta.client.download_file('testsweta','test5gb','test5gb',**Config=config**)
```

Answer (score 1):

it works for me using Version: 1.16.30 to download a 10MB file

boto3.client('s3').download_file('BUCKET_NAME', 'OBJECT_NAME', 'FILE_NAME')

Comment: Thank you Jonathan Leon. I am using a cloud based tool. The Boto3 library comes with the tool. Will be looking into how to update to a newer version of Boto3.